# Using Apache License 2.0 library inside a company

Tags: apache-2.0

I implemented a little console application in C# (tool) that can go through the web pages on the site and get information, links, files from them. I used Selenium for this purpose. Two nuget packages [WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/2.53.0) and [ChromeDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/2.23.0) (the last is unlicensed). But WebDriver has Apache 2.0 license.

I don't actually understand very well how we can use projects under this license. My tool will be just pushed to github (private repository, because it is for my company) and used only locally, on my computer, or someone else. This tool is just for our company, it is not for sale.

What should I do or, probably, add to the code, to abide the law?

Comment: If only your company uses it, you don't publish anything. The copyleft property of these open source licenses only applies if you publish your tool. So don't make it available to the public and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything (except maybe make clear within your company that this tool is not to be redistributed outside the company).
All open source licenses allow private modification and private use without any restriction.

As for the second package, you say that it is unlicensed but I can read:

> "chromedriver.exe" is licensed under the New BSD License.

So I guess it is actually free software as well and the same considerations apply. Otherwise, putting it online like that looks like at least a permission for private use anyways.